# How to pass external variables to a private javascript outer closure function?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, oop, closures

I may have made some poor design choices on this one. I have several objects being instanced like this.

```
core.modules.trial = function(sandbox){
  return{
    alert_private : function(){
      alert(omgpi);
    }
  };
};
```

I would like to do this:

```
   core.modules.trial[omgpi] = "external private var";

    var trial = core.modules.trial();

    trial.alert_private(); //would hopefully output "external private var"
```

I am trying to assign the **omgpi** variable to the private scope of the outer function. Normally you would do var omgpi within the outer function before returning anything. But I am trying to do this from an external script when this function is called

Comment: without modifying core.modules.trial, afaik you can only do this with a global variable (window.omgpi)

Answer (score 1):

You can monkey-patch core.modules.trial:

```
var old_constructor = core.modules.trial;
core.modules.trial = function(sandbox) {
  this.omgpi = 'whatever'; // or an object you can add to as desired
  return old_constructor.call(this, sandbox); // rebinds to this this
};
```

See the documentation for [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call).

Comment: this does not work as omgpi is called as an external symbol. have you tried it ?

Comment: This is very close to what I am trying to accomplish but wouldn't I have to prepend everything with this in the public methods? Also gpilontino is correct this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
core.modules.trial = function(sandbox){
  var c = arguments.callee;
  return{
    alert_private : function(){
      alert(c.omgpi);
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
core.modules.trial = function(sandbox){
  var self = {
    alert_private: function(){
      alert(self.omgpi);
    }
  };

  return self;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need omgpi to be in the closure, you need to set it from within. You can't set things in closures you're not a part of.

```
core.modules.trial = function(sandbox){

    ///////////////////////////
    var omgpi = this.omgpi;
    ///////////////////////////

    return{
        alert_private : function(){
            alert(omgpi);
        }
    };
};
```

But whenever you call core.modules.trial(), `this` refers to *modules* because that's like the parent. So you could stick the value in modules like this:

```
core.modules.omgpi = "external private var";
```

Then the rest works:

```
var trial = core.modules.trial();
trial.alert_private(); // alerts "external private var"
```

By the way, your original code had a bug:

```
core.modules.trial[omgpi]
```

This uses the *value* of the variable omgpi as the key. You want either `core.modules.trial.omgpi` or `core.modules.trial["omgpi"]`.

Comment: thx darkporter, I have a lot of these modules similair to .trial that I am trying to avoid duplicating code in. Is there any way I can automate this var assignment in the .modules object or the core? so that the individual modules inherit it?

Comment: I suspect this code could be _way_ simplified. In your example will `trial` be called multiple times with different `omgpi` values? I.e. will you be doing this:

    core.modules.omgpi = "external private var";
    var trial = core.modules.trial();
    ... later ...
    core.modules.omgpi = "new value";
    var otherTrial = core.modules.trial();